# Using nested classes for organizing exceptions

Tags: c#, class, exception

Is there anything wrong with doing the following for organizing code - specifically exceptions?

```
public class QueryParameterException
{
    public class BooleanArgumentException : ArgumentException
    {
        public BooleanArgumentException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }
    }

    public class DoubleArgumentException : ArgumentException
    {
        public DoubleArgumentException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }
    }

    public class IntArgumentException : ArgumentException
    {
        public IntArgumentException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And referencing them like this:

```
throw new QueryParameterException.BooleanArgumentException($"invalid argument '{queryStringValue}' for boolean parameter '{key}' should be 'true' or 'false'");
```

Reason not duplicate - inheritance is not relevant.

Comment: You mean technically or something else? If it works, it works.

Comment: This question fits Code Review Exchange. And why not use namespaces?

Comment: Why not just namespace?

Comment: @GiladGreen sorry, didn't realise this was more fitting to Code Review Exchange. I totally forgot I could use namespaces like that. I think the underlining that ReSharper gives it with the message "Namespace does not correspond to file location" somewhat put me off. Would you recommend using namespaces?

Comment: @Sinatr I didn't ask anything about inheriting an Exception.

Comment: @PatrickHofman it sure works. Just always wondering if there is a better/more correct way of doing such things! :)

Comment: It sounds very subjective to me then.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues.

First, if you nest inside a class instead of using a namespace it appears to work the same except you can't move the outer class name to a `using` statement if you're going to reference it multiple times. You have to use the full outer and inner class name every time.

The second is subjective. Some future developer might spend an extra 30 seconds or so trying to figure out what's going on. He/she might see

```
throw new QueryParameterException.BooleanArgumentException($"...");
```

and feel the need to look at the declarations of `QueryParameterException` and `BooleanArgumentException` even though it has nothing to do with his current task.

When he gets there he will confirm that these are just nested classes and it's okay. No big deal, go back to the current task. But he'll still scratch his head and wonder why that was done. Even though it works, using a class as a namespace is unusual. Once he realizes that someone has done something odd for no apparent reason his confidence in the code will by slightly eroded (maybe just 3%) and going forward he'll spend more time checking things he probably doesn't need to check just to make sure there's nothing odd going on.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I see your points especially the last one - I often spend time checking things to see what is going on - hence why I asked the question to get the better/correct way of doing it.